# Returning a pointer to a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I am confused with the `return` value of a **pointer to a structure**.
I have written an `AVL Tree`. This is my header-file snippet-

```
typedef struct AVLNode {
    struct AVLNode  *left,
                    *right;
    int value,
        height;
} AVLNode;

typedef struct AVLNode *AVLTree;
AVLNode *delet(int value, AVLTree t);
```

and here is my `delet()` and `main()`-

```
AVLNode *delet(int value, AVLTree t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        printf("Node not found\n");
        return t;
    }
    else if (value == t->value) {
        .....
        return t;
    }
    else if (value < t->value) {
        if (t->left != NULL) {
            t->left = delet(value, t->left);
        }       
        if (height(t->left) - height(t->right) == 2) {
            if (t->value < t->left->value)
                    t = rotateR(t);
            else
                    t = rotateLR(t);
        }
        .....
        return t;
    }
    else if (value > t->value) {
        if (t->right != NULL) {
            t->right = delet(value, t->right);
        }
        .....
        return t;
    }
}

void main()
{
    AVLTree t = NULL;
    .....
    t = delet(4, t);    /* works fine */
    delet(4, t);        /* gives improper results */
    .....
}
```

Here, I return `t`(which is of type `AVLNode *`). While I realise that this is essential
 in recursive `delet()` call, what I do not understand is -

- when I call `t = delet(4, t)` from `main()` it gives me proper results, whereas, just calling `delet(4, t)` gives wrong result.
- if I am passing a pointer in `delet(t)` (`t` is an `AVLNode *`), why do I need to collect it in a pointer again?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what "works fine" and "gives improper results" are supposed to mean? Can you describe what you're expecting, and how what you're seeing is different from what you're expecting?

Comment: in delete() you passed copy of structure.try `delete(4,&t) `

Comment: @JKB: Technically, its not a copy of the structure, just a copy of the pointer (AVLTree is a typedef)

Comment: Theoretically, no need to collect a pointer in the return value. Usually, the delete() function returns the nodes that is deleted.

Comment: @missingno yes but depend on declaration of `t`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths what I mean is - my tree traversal gives unexpected results. Some of the nodes are missing when I use just `delet()` as against `t = delet()`.

Comment: @missingno Can you please elaborate. Am I not passing by reference? I have used a pointer to `AVLNode`.

Comment: @yadav_vishal please look my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have passed `AVLTree t` "by value". Pass the address of `t` to `delet` then modify it.

Right now you are only modifying the local copy of `AVLTree t` which you declared in the `delet` function:
`AVLNode *delet(int value, AVLTree t)`

Try declaring the function as `AVLNode *delet(int value, AVLTree *p_t)`, and the call will be `delet(4, &t);`.

**EDIT:** (AT OP's Comment)

When you need to modify a value inside a function:

```
void swap(int a, int b)
{
  int t;
  t = a;
  a = b;
  b = t;
}
```

This doesn't work because you needed to modify `a` and `b` whose "copies" you pased to the function.

Similarly in your case you need to modify the address held by pointer `AVLTree t`, i.e. the pointer itself, therefore "address of the pointer" needs to be passed here not the copy of address held by pointer.

Comment: `typedef struct AVLNode *AVLTree;`

Comment: @Kevin : OP is modifying the pointer itself not the value at the address pointed by pointer therefore **"the pointer is passed by value"**

Comment: @Kevin This is exactly what I have declared.

Comment: @MadHatter can you explain how it is **passed by value**?

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks. I think I need to go back and read pointer, call by reference. Again. If you can point me to some reference, that'll be great.

Comment: Telling a beginner they're passing a pointer by value is just going to confuse them; usually you explain how they're passing a whole struct by value.  Furthermore, he doesn't show any code where he reassigns the pointer, so what is passing a pointer to a pointer going to do besides confuse him?

Comment: @Kevin actually I am reassigning the pointers. I didn't mention it for brevity. I have edited the code to show that.

Answer (score 1):

you need this

```
 AVLNode *delet(int value, AVLTree* t)

AVLTree t;
 delet(4,&t);
```